# Apache server setup virtualhost that points to folder

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

i am trying to setup a virtualhost so that the url:

```
system.domain.dk
```

Will point to another directory than

```
domain.dk
```

So far this is what i have:

http.conf:

```
    <VirtualHost *:1500>
     ServerAdmin webmaster@example.org
     DocumentRoot /var/www/system_learningbank/
     ServerName system.learnbypower.dk
     ServerAlias system.learnbypower.dk
     ErrorLog /var/www/learnbypower.dk/logs/error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts:

```
89.104.220.207:1500    system.learnbypower.dk
```

However when i go to system.learnbypower.dk it directs me to the original documentroot and not `/var/www/system_learningbank/`

So what am i missing ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have configured the vhost to answer to port 1500. You have to enter

```
http://system.learnbypower.dk:1500
```

to connect to this.

To use port 80 instead (the default http port), replace `<VirtualHost *:1500>` with `<VirtualHost *:80>`.

Also, ports cannot be specified in the `hosts` file.